# validating a user's value length (javascript)

Tags: validation

I am practicing my javascript beginners knowledge on a simple form. I want the user to enter a 10 digits phone number (in case it's less than 10 or more than 10 I have created the invalid style class so the user will only be allowed to enter 10 digits for his phone number). Also, once they entered the phone number of 10 digits, the user should be able to click "+" and get a second box for a second phone number (the second box will appear when you click + only if the user entered 10 digits for his first phone number). 
I used an if() for validating the phone number, but it doesn't seem to work. Below is my code, any ideas maybe?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Numere de telefon</title>
    <style>
        .invalid {
            background-color: rgb(139,0,0,0.2);
            color: darkgreen;
            border: 1px green solid;
        }
    </style>
    <script>
        function minL(elem,event,nr){
            var v = elem.value; 
            if(v.length < nr ){
                elem.classList.add("invalid");
            } else if (v.length > nr) {
                elem.classList.add("invalid");
            } else {
                elem.classList.remove("invalid");
            }
        }

         function addInput(elem,event){
            event.preventDefault(); 
            var container = document.querySelector("#containerNrTel"); 
            if(minL(document.querySelector("[name=numarTelefon]"))){
                container.innerHTML += '<input type="text" placeholder="nr telefon" />'; 
            }

        }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Cont nou</legend>
        <input type="text" placeholder="nume">
        <input type="text" placeholder="prenume">
        <input type="text" placeholder="nr telefon" name="numarTelefon" oninput="" onchange="minL(this,event,10);">
        <input type="button" value="+" onclick="addInput(this,event);">
        <div id="containerNrTel"></div>
        <input type="button" value="Submit">
    </fieldset>
    </form>    
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance,
Ioana

Answer (score 0):

There are two main issues.

1. The call to minL in the addInput function doesn't have the right number of parameters.
2. minL doesn't return a boolean value when addInput expects it to.

   ```
   function minL(elem,event,nr){
       var v = elem.value; 
       if(v.length < nr ){
           elem.classList.add("invalid");
       } else if (v.length > nr) {
           elem.classList.add("invalid");
       } else {
           elem.classList.remove("invalid");
           return true;
       }
   }

    function addInput(elem,event){
       event.preventDefault(); 
       var container = document.querySelector("#containerNrTel"); 
       if(minL(document.querySelector("[name=numarTelefon]"), event, 10)){
           container.innerHTML += '<input type="text" placeholder="nr telefon" />'; 
       }

   }
   ```